# Accept or reject change tracking in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I have multiple XML files which consists of change tracking attribute `<atict:add>` or `<atict:del>`.

Objective:

- if XML file consists of an element `CT="ACCEPT"` then accept/print all tags with `<atict:add>` and ignore `<atict:del>`
- if XML file consits of an element `CT="REJECT"` then accept/print all tags with `<atict:del>` and ignore `<atict:accept>`

**Sample XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict" **CT="ACCEPT"**>
<PARA>abcd <atict:del>efghi</atict:del><atict:add>1456790
</atict:add></PARA>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict" **CT="ACCEPT"**>
<PARA>abcd <atict:del>efghi</atict:del><atict:add>1456790
</atict:add></PARA>
```

**Output XML after processing:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict" **CT="ACCEPT"**>
<PARA>abcd <atict:add>1456790
</atict:add></PARA>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict" **CT="ACCEPT"**>
<PARA>abcd <atict:add>1456790
</atict:add></PARA>
```

How can I add the CT in the XSLT with an if condition to satisfy the criteria?

Comment: Two template matches for `add` and `del`. With a test on `::ancestor@CT="ACCEPT/REJECT"` for matching further.

Comment: Thanks Joop, like this? <xsl:template match="atict:add//text()">
      <xsl:if test::ancestor@CT="ACCEPT">

Comment: Yes, though not exactly, I thought of a match `add` not its `text()`, and of course `test="::ancestor[@CT='ACCEPT']" or such, _lately not done XSLT_ - By the way there are nice cheat sheets on XSLT in the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample stylesheet below does the job. See the comments for explanations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="CT_stat">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="DM/@CT = 'ACCEPT'">1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="DM/@CT = 'REJECT'">0</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>2</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- identity template  -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template matching for atict:del and atict:add, retaining
             them or deleting them based on $CT_stat variable -->    
    <xsl:template match="atict:del">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$CT_stat=1"/>
            <xsl:when test="$CT_stat=0">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="atict:add">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$CT_stat=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$CT_stat=0"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the xsl Joel. But the above xsl removes the <atict:add> and <atict:del> element and also the value associated with it. I think somehow it is not detecting the CT="ACCEPT" or "REJECT" and the if condition.

Comment: Sorry for the above comment Joel. This one works with a bit of modification!!

Comment: Can we add a third condition to the existsing XSL. if CT='"" then accept both <atict:add> and <atict:del>?

Comment: I have modified my answer. It accepts both if CT is neither ACCEPT nor REJECT.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel. Much appreciated.!

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="atict:del[ancestor::DM/@CT='ACCEPT']"/>
<xsl:template match="atict:add[ancestor::DM/@CT='REJECT']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. But the above xsl removes the <atict:add> and <atict:del> element and also the value associated with it.

Comment: I guess it is not detecting the CT

Comment: "*the above xsl removes the <atict:add> and <atict:del> element and also the value associated with it*" Isn't that what it's supposed to do? If not, please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael.. The above xsl was very useful!!

Comment: Actually the above one was supposed to remove atict:add with value when CT="REJECT" and remove atict:del with value when CT="ACCEPT"

Comment: Thanks a lot but I used your concept also for building my xsl.

Comment: "*Actually the above one was supposed to remove atict:add with value when CT="REJECT" and remove atict:del with value when CT="ACCEPT"*" Isn't that exactly what it does?

Comment: Can we add a third condition to accept both<atict:add> and <atict:del> if CT=""..Thanks

Comment: @ShravanVishwanathan There is no need to add anything; this is how it behaves now.